# data from msdk to osdk is lost very very often

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm using osdk3.6 and msdk4.6(android).

I'm sending data from android to osdk,

but data is lost very very often and it is almost unusable.

I edited osdk3.6 mobile sample.

parseFromMobileCallback() is hardly called(but not zero).

Does anyone have any suggestions(changing sdk version or something)?

Answer (score 0):

how much is the size of data you sent?Actually,the upstream (mobile device to onboard computer) bandwidth is approximately 1KB/s while the downstream (onboard computer to mobile device) bandwidth is approximately 8KB/s

Comment: I'm sending very very few data from android to UAV (like 2 bytes ).
 Does msdk->osdk transfering have no reliablity?
 Should I send command continuously?

Comment: It should be reliable. I am using it with 4.9 Android MSDK and 3.7 OSDK. Does your DJI Go app or another app say that your signal is good? Is the signal unreliable when you are testing with both units next to each other? No, you should not send the command continuously. You should develop ack functionality: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/3.6/sample/linux/mobile/mobile_sample.cpp#L208